# said to have multiple labels in math environment

Tags: equations, cross-referencing

I basically have the following LaTeX code which is supposed to show a numbered equation and a reference to this equation:

```
\[ i^2 = j^2 = k^2 = -1 \]
\begin{equation} \label{eq:ijk}
  ijk = -1.
\end{equation}
Now you take \autoref{eq:ijk} and...
```

The Problem is, that when building the file with XeTeX I get an error message like

```
! Package amsmath Error: Multiple \label's: label 'eq:ijk' will be lost.

See the amsmath package documentation for explanation.
```

Any suggestions how to solve this error or how to post something useful here about this on tex.sx?

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}

\renewcommand{\theequation}{\ac{Gl.}~\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{equation}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \label{eq:ijk}
  ijk = -1.
\end{equation}
Now you take \autoref{eq:ijk} and make something like\ldots

\end{document}
```

Comment: Here's a suggestion: provide the community with a complete, [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that replicates the problem. We want to be able to copy-and-paste-and-compile and see exactly the problem you're seeing. It should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Since your very minimal example works, something you deleted to make it is what is causing the problem. That should be a clue for you. If you're still puzzled, post the smallest example that _does_ cause the problem.

Comment: Hmm.. I could post the full document (which has about 30 pages). I'll try to somehow get an example that does not work. :)

Comment: Is there an `eq:ijk` label anywhere else in that long document?

Comment: no.. just two `\autoref`s

Comment: This is at least a example which reproduces the error.. Don't really know, if it's minimal

Comment: never put display math such as `\[` or `\begin{equation}` one after the other, the spacing will be all wrong, use a multiline display such as `align`

Comment: @Uroc327: This is not minimal, since you don't need all the font-related changes. Remove all unnecessary packages and macros until just before the problem doesn't show up anymore.

Comment: don't load inputenc as you must be using xetex or luatex)

Comment: @Werner I've deleted everything non-related stuff and then the error disappeared. As said in the original post, I'm not able to reproduce a minimal **and** non-working example.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for that! Does it make sense though to put two equations without alignment into a `align` environment?

Comment: @Uroc327 use gather or multline if no alignment but please fix your example don't delete _everything_ delete things _one at a time_  checking it still has the problem then post what remains

Comment: The error arises because of the way you redefine `\theequation`.

Comment: @Uroc327: No, after I remove the [`pstricks`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pstricks) and [`tikz`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf)-related stuff, I still get the same problem. That means your example is not minimal. Also, you don't need the header-related stuff ([`fancyhdr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fanchdr), for example)...

Comment: @Uroc327: I've updated your post to reflect what could be considered a minimal example. That is, all the irrelevant crap was removed.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle but when using a multiline display, I can't have the first line numbered and the second not, correct?

Comment: @Uroc327 - Sure you can. Look into the `\notag` instruction.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve by prefixing `\ac{Gl.}` to the equation numbers? In particular, why the `\ac` directive?

Comment: @Mico thanks! I'll look into that.. On the first use I want the word for `Equation` (german Gleichung) and then I want the abbreviation `Eq.` (german `Gl.`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using the `amsmath` package (indirectly, since you're loading the `mathtools` package), you shouldn't manipulate `\theequation` directly. Instead, you should modify the higher-level macro `\tagform@`. I really wouldn't insert an acronym-generating macro inside `\tagform@`. Do you think your readers, the members of your thesis committee, or anyone else will be unsure about "Gl." could mean? Separately, I suggest you look into loading the `cleveref` package, in part because it features nice language localizations, including for German. An additional bonus is that `\cref` will automatically surround equation numbers with parentheses, which is the case with `\autoref`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}
\usepackage[noabbrev]{cleveref}

%%\renewcommand{\theequation}{\ac{Gl.}~\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{equation}}
\makeatletter
\def\tagform@#1{\maketag@@@{(\ignorespaces Gl.~#1\unskip\@@italiccorr)}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\setcounter{chapter}{1}  % just for this example

\begin{equation}
  \label{eq:ijk}
  ijk = -1.
\end{equation}
Now you take \cref{eq:ijk} and make something like\ldots

\end{document}
```

Comment: The `cref` doesn't always do the same as I want but thanks for the hint to the `renewcommand` and the tag :)

Comment: @Uroc327 - What do you want to do that `\cref` doesn't do?